# Trying to add laravel/homestead to Vagrant finishes in an error: The box failed to unpackage properly

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

This issue has been following me for about few days now.
Using:

- Virtual Box 5.2.18
- Vagrant 2.0.2 (also with version 2.1.5)
- MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6
- Ruby 2.5.1

When I call command **vagrant box add laravel/homestead** it ends up with following error:

```
box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v6.3.0) for provider: virtualbox
box: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/6.3.0/providers/virtualbox.box
The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box
file you're trying to add is not corrupted and that enough disk space
is available and then try again.
The output from attempting to unpackage (if any):

bsdtar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/Users/someone/.vagrant.d/tmp/box294969b313e1338f0cd6a347f68be3b599016863'
```

I have 100GB free disk space storage on my computer, so it's not the problem with this...

**I've tried:**

- reinstalling Vagrant
- updating macOS
- deleting vagrant.d/tmp folder and trying to add box laravel/homestead which ended up with error
- downgrading Virtual Box
- repeating command many times hahahh

Any idea would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the solution to the OP, But I had similar issue to this one on Windows OS.

> The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box file
> you're trying to add is not corrupted and that enough disk space is
> available and then try again.

Turns out the disk size vagrant was warning about was my user directory(Disk 1). I had the vagrant file itself in different disk altogether (Disk 2). Once I made enough space on Disk 1. Vagrant could proceed to download fine.